# Inject Dynamic resource to Spring Batch ItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have wrote a Custom Item reader which needs to accept the resource dynamically from rest  endpoint.
It reads file from byte code.

```
public class CustomItemReader implements ItemReader<File> {

    @Setter
    private MyResourceModel resource; //simple pojo that includes byte codes and file name;

    @Override
    public File read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        //converting resource to file;
    }
}
```

in many  examples that i reviewed recently the resource injected in config which means statically but in my case I have to inject it on my controller.

In order to do that i inject my reader to controller, and inject resource to this reader.

this is the config where i initiate this bean;

```
@Configuration
public class MyStepConfig {

    @Bean("customItemReader")
    public CustomItemReader reader() {
        CustomItemReader reader = new CustomItemReader();
        //reader.setResource(resource);  // in many code resource is injected here but i need to inject in endpoint method.
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean("myStep")
    public Step step() {
        //inject reader to step...
    }
}
```

the controller is below;

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Qualifier("customItemReader")
    private CustomItemReader customItemReader;

    @PostMapping("/upload-file")
    public ResponseEntity uploadFile(@RequestBody MyResourceModel resource) {
        customItemReader.setResource(resource);

        //launch job

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

It works but i don't know it is the correct way? 
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about code review an should be ask at [codereview.se]

Comment: @Jens ok, I didn't know that this kind of question should be ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com. I will ask it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current solution is not thread safe (if there are two requests to start job second request will change resource model for first job).

I would suggest to create your reader as job scope bean, and pass required configuration by job parameters:

```
  @Bean("customItemReader")
  @JobScope
  public CustomItemReader reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['param']}") String param) {
    CustomItemReader reader = new CustomItemReader(param);
    //reader.setResource(resource);  // in many code resource is injected here but i need to inject in endpoint method.
    return reader;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, i understand the thread safe solution but what is the param? where should i inject it? My reader has not param field.

Comment: You should pass parameters during launching of the job. They are persisted in database, so you cannot pass there complex objects. You should redesign your CustomItemReader to allow constructing with simple types and pass them all by parameters (this was only example with one param). Read more at https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html